# JMeter groovy language throws 'unable to resolve class' but beanshell or java are fine

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am using JMeter 4.0.  Below is some code I have in a JSR223 Sampler.  It looks in a directory and locates a specific file.

```
//This looks in the test results folder and locates
//the most recent file with the testReport prefix we are looking for

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; 
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;

//show some logging in the jmeter log and in the jenkins console
log.info("=== get Test Results File to Upload ===");
OUT.println("=== get Test Results File to Upload ===");

//put the test_results_path property in a string to make it easier to work with
String dir_path = props.get("test_results_path");
log.info("=== test_results_path === "+dir_path);
OUT.println("=== test_results_path === "+dir_path);
String rpt_pref = props.get("testReport_prefix");
//log.info("=== testReport_prefix === "+rpt_pref);
//OUT.println("=== testReport_prefix === "+rpt_pref);
String rpt_suff = props.get("testReport_suffix");
//log.info("=== testReport_suffix === "+rpt_suff);
//OUT.println("=== testReport_suffix === "+rpt_suff);

//define an empty file
File theNewestFile = null;
try {
   File dir = new File(dir_path);
   //log.info("=== file directory === "+dir);   
   //OUT.println("=== file directory === "+dir);   
   FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(""+rpt_pref+"*."+rpt_suff+"");    
   //log.info("=== fileName === "+fileFilter);
   //OUT.println("=== fileName === "+fileFilter);   

   File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
   if (files.length > 0) {
        /** The newest file comes first **/
        Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
        theNewestFile = files[0];
        String fileName = files[0].getName().toString();
        log.info("=== File to Upload === "+fileName);
        OUT.println("=== File to Upload === "+fileName);
        props.put("varResultsReportFile",fileName);
   } else if(files.length <= 0) {
            /** no files exist **/
            //theNewestFile = ;
            String fileName = "FILE_MISSING";
            log.error("*FAILED to find file for "+vars.get("testApp")+" ===  "+fileName);
        OUT.println("*FAILED to find file for "+vars.get("testApp")+" ===  "+fileName);
        //SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
        SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true);
        //SampleResult.setResponseData("FILE_MISSING");
        props.put("varResultsReportFile",fileName);
   }

    return theNewestFile;
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
   log.error("*FAILED - Something bad happened", ex);
   throw ex;
}
```

When I run this with Language = BeanShell or Java, it runs fine.  When I try using Language = groovy, it gives me this error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script16.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.io.filefilter
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter;
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:183) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:215) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script16.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.io.filefilter
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter;
```

I've checked and I seem go have commons-io.jar that comes with jmeter 4.0 in my lib folder.  I upgraded my java jdk to 8_181.  What else can I do?  For now I will run using beanshell but would like to convert to groovy since this is jmeter's preferred language over beanshell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got this code but it does something very weird. Even if you resolve all you compilation and other issues it will not work as your whole test will stop at this line:

```
SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true);
```

and will not go further.

The easier way to find the newest file basing on prefix and suffix would be something like:

```
File theNewestFile = new File(props.get("test_results_path")).listFiles().findAll {
    it.getName().startsWith(props.get("testReport_prefix")) && it.getName().endsWith(props.get("testReport_suffix"))
}?.sort { -it.lastModified() }?.head()
```

References:

- [Groovy.sort()](http://sergiodelamo.es/groovy-sorting/)
- [Groovy.find()](http://grails.asia/groovy-find)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: This is working so much better than the other code.  Thanks again Dmitri.  You rock!!

Comment: Also to make it case-insensitive, changed to this:   it.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(rpt_pref.toLowerCase()) && it.getName().endsWith(rpt_suff)

Answer (score 1):

Remove unused import:

```
  import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter;
```

`filefilter` is a java package(not class) and doesn't need to be imported.